# Gradle task behaves differently with Type modifier

Tags: gradle

I have a task that I need to configure to depend on another existing release task.  I have written the code snippet as below and it works fine - files are copied into bundleDir as expected:

```
task releaseJarsTask1 (dependsOn: releaseTask) {
    copy {
        from fileTree(dir: releaseRepoDir, include: (releaseTask.project.name + '*/*.jar')).files
        into bundleDir
    }
}
```

Based on my relatively new understanding of Gradle, the following should also work, but it does not - it produces no output:

```
task releaseJarsTask2 (dependsOn: releaseTask, type: Copy) {
    from fileTree(dir: releaseRepoDir, include: (releaseTask.project.name + '*/*.jar')).files
    into bundleDir
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

It was working before only incidentally. In the first task you are performing the copy during the configuration phase, since the call to `copy()` is done in a configuration closure. In the second task, the copy operation will only be done when the task is executed. Try manually executing the task with `gradle releaseJarsTask2`.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  That was indeed the issue as I was trying to hook into a BNDTools based release task - I had this wrapped in gradle.taskGraph.whenReady, which meant that the tasks were not being configured for execution.  When I removed it and made a couple of other dependency changes, it started working.